# Different InnerHTML Output For Selected Value Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically what I want here is to create a hidden paragraph and when each value is selected the hidden paragraph shows the custom text I set up for each value .  So basically if I select Audi I wanna type : Random Text / for BMW > Whatever / Mercedes > car ,

the whole point is to customize the text its shown for each value selected

Totally need this so any help is more than appreciated !

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you put whatever text you want for each car name as the value ?

Comment: because I dont know how to do that lol

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understood your question but I think this is a possible solution:

```
function myFunction() {
    let messages = {
        Audi: 'Haldo for: ',
        BMW: 'Maldo for: ',
        Mercedes: 'Baldo for',
        Volvo: 'Marioldo for'
    }
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `${messages[x]} ${x}`;
}
myFunction(); // Now run the funtion for a init
```

I create a JSON with n keys with the value of single option of select, and use the value of select like selector for get the string asigned to key in the JSON.

**UPDATE WITH QUESTION IN COMMENT**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

      <body>

        <p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

        <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
          <option value="Audi">Audi
          <option value="BMW">BMW
          <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
          <option value="Volvo">Volvo
        </select>

        <p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <ul id="list">

        </ul>


        <script>
          function myFunction() {
            let messages = {
              Audi: {
                brandName: 'Haldo for: ',
                features: ['Magic', 'free', 'furry']
              },
              BMW: {
                brandName: 'Maldo for: ',
                features: ['lovely']
              },
              Mercedes: {
                brandName: 'Baldo for',
                features: ['twirling', 'tasty']
              },
              Volvo: {
                brandName: 'Marioldo for',
                features: ['bar', 'foo', 'zio']
              }
            }
            var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `${messages[x].brandName} ${x}`;


            let ul = document.getElementById("list")

            ul.innerHTML = '';
            for (let feat of messages[x].features) {
              console.log(feat)
              var li = document.createElement('li');
              li.innerHTML = feat;
              ul.appendChild(li);
            }



          }
          myFunction();

        </script>

      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing this , think you got my point , question is however : Assuming Audi is the default select option , how can the text be printed by default ?

Comment: It's sufficent to run the function after you declare it with `myFunction();`. 
I'll update my answer.

Comment: Dude you're a life saver really thanks a lot , one last thing though , I'm trying to use this setup for product variant details on my shop, so basically I tried inserting product details surrounded by  <ol> <li> tags but the function was not working for that variant , can you please let me know how can I make bull points describing each product with your setup ?

Comment: So basically if I select Audi  > I will get the following : 1. German Car 2. Diesel 3. 200 HP etc etc , point here is that I want the details to be sorted by using bullet points , one detail per line @AITheLazyMonkey

Comment: I think you mean to use <ul> instead of <ol>.
`<ul>
  <li>German Car</li>
  <li>Diesel 3. 200 HP</li>
  <li>Maldo Maldo</li>
  <li>....</li>
</ul>`

Comment: I'm trying to insert this text  but it doesnt work : <ol>
<li>Free Shipping</li>
<li>40 Day Returns </li>
<li>Lightweight</li>
<li>100% US Made</li>
</ol>

Comment: yes exactly  , thats what I need , please refer to my recent comment

Comment: It's necessary use a more complex JSON with the property to show in the list, but it's a bad idea use this method if you have more than 4 car brand. If you want i update the code, but I advise against to use it

Comment: I've exactly 4 products to select from , do you think its cool if I go with it ?

Comment: If you don't need more than that, this is a simple and good solution.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a data attribut with the random data, something like:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="selectionChanged(this)">
  <option value="Audi" data="random audi data">Audi
  <option value="BMW" data="random bmw data">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes" data="random mercedes data">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo" data="random volvo data">Volvo
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function selectionChanged(selectObj) {

  var carData = selectObj.options[selectObj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data');

  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x+ " with car data "+carData;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This way you can keep the data together with the options, so you dont need to keep track of it elsewhere.

Comment: hey , thanks a lot for the answer , what I need here is different text output which I can manually type for each car selected , so basically if I select Audit I wanna type >Fan of Audi , if I select Mercedes I wanna type > Mercedes is Great

Answer (score -1):

You can make String Arrays of the random texts.

Comment: and how can I do that ?